# Bash - how to put each line within quotation

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I want to put each line within quotation marks, such as:

```
abcdefg
hijklmn
opqrst
```

convert to:

```
"abcdefg"
"hijklmn"
"opqrst"
```

How to do this in Bash shell script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  Your question isn't bad but it is ambiguous, or maybe just a bit incomplete.  Where are the lines coming from -- from a file, or an array of variables, or lines in a single variable (or somewhere else)?  Where does the output need to go?  Into a variable, an array, a file, somewhere else?  The answers so far show a variety of possiblilities (and don't cover all the scenarios I mention).

Comment: Also, an awful lot of people seem to want to do this for the wrong reasons. If you have a program which requires its arguments to be in quotes, like `./tool "example sentence one" "example sentence two"`, the quotes are consumed by the shell, and not part of the data itself. If you have those values in variables, the variables should not contain the quotes, but you need to quote the interpolation; `./tool "$sentence1" "$sentence2"`

Answer (score 55):

Using **awk**

```
awk '{ print "\""$0"\""}' inputfile
```

Using **pure bash**

```
while read FOO; do
   echo -e "\"$FOO\""
done < inputfile
```

where `inputfile` would be a file containing the lines without quotes.

If your file has empty lines, **awk** is definitely the way to go:

```
awk 'NF { print "\""$0"\""}' inputfile
```

`NF` tells `awk` to only execute the print command when the Number of Fields is more than zero (line is not empty).

Comment: for the `read` solution, you need `IFS= read -r FOO`. Otherwise you'll lose whitespace at the beginning of lines and backslash-escapes my be lost

Comment: Or lose the `FOO` and use the implicit `$REPLY` name. Just do `while read; do printf '"%s"\n' "$REPLY"; done < inputfile`

Comment: all more reasons to go with `awk` as I see it :D

Comment: @glennjackman sure, if you actually want to retain backslash escapes.

Comment: `s/line is not empty/line is not blank/`. Note that the `-e` is not needed and will actually alter the content if it contains backslashes.

Answer (score 18):

I use the following command:

```
xargs -I{lin} echo \"{lin}\" < your_filename
```

The `xargs` take standard input (redirected from your file) and pass one line a time to `{lin}` placeholder, and then execute the command at next, in this case a `echo` with escaped double quotes.

You can use the `-i` option of xargs to omit the name of the placeholder, like this:

```
xargs -i echo \"{}\" < your_filename
```

In both cases, your IFS must be at default value or with `'\n'` at least.

Comment: Consider also, that one might not really need to echo the thing, but one might have needed quote-marks to do other operations in the script. For me, I can run a command:
       script-that-lists-files-per-line.py | xargs -I{lin} sudo chmod a+r {lin}

Comment: You're right Mr. macetw, my mistake not put clear that's just an command example.

Comment: Using mingw xargs 4.4.2 on windows 10 from command prompt found >xargs -I{lin} echo "'"lin"'" worked for single quotes.

Answer (score 15):

This sed should work for ignoring empty lines as well:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^..*$/"&"/' inFile
```

or

```
sed 's/^.\{1,\}$/"&"/' inFile
```

Answer (score 11):

Use sed:

```
sed -e 's/^\|$/"/g' file
```

More effort needed if the file contains empty lines.

Comment: I tried this and discovered that, for some reason, on blank lines it only output one quote.

Comment: Could do `sed 's/.*/"&"/'`

Comment: @glennjackman: Yes. If the line is empty, there is only one position when the substitution can be tried.

Comment: sed 's/^/"/; s/$/"/' file, assuming no line is already quoted.

Answer (score 3):

I think the sed and awk are the best solution but if you want to use just shell  here is small script for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

chr="\""
file="file.txt"
cp $file $file."_backup"
while read -r line
do
 echo "${chr}$line${chr}"
done <$file > newfile
mv newfile $file
```

Comment: it would be nice to at least provide some explanation as why you feel this is incorrect.

Comment: Other than showing how to output a literal double quotation mark, it does not address the topic of adding quotation marks to preexisting text at all.

Comment: @ chepner I have modified my comment and thanks for giving me a feedback so I can contribute more effectively.

Answer (score 3):

```
paste -d\" /dev/null your-file /dev/null
```

(not the nicest looking, but probably the fastest)

Now, if the input may contain quotes, you may need to escape them with backslashes (and then escape backslashes as well) like:

```
sed 's/["\]/\\&/g; s/.*/"&"/' your-file
```

Comment: I appreciate this solution because it only required me to escape a single quotation mark when embedding the command where I needed to escape every one as `\\\"`.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223712) worked for me in `mac terminal`.

```
$ awk '{ printf "\"%s\",\n", $0 }' your_file_name
```

It should be noted that the *text* in *double quotes* and *commas* was printed out in terminal, the file itself was unaffected.

Answer (score -3):

I used sed with two expressions to replace start and end of line, since in my particular use case I wanted to place HTML tags around only lines that contained particular words.

So I searched for the lines containing words contained in the `bla` variable within the text file `inputfile` and replaced the beginnign with `<P>` and the end with `</P>` (well actually I did some longer HTML tagging in the real thing, but this will serve fine as example)

Similar to:

```
$ bla=foo
$ sed -e "/${bla}/s#^#<P>#" -e "/${bla}/s#\$#</P>#" inputfile
<P>foo</P>
bar
$
```