# How can I add " around each line bash

Tags: bash

I have a file with one word on each line, I want to add a `"` before the word, and a `",` after the word with Bash.

Example:

```
Hello
Sleep
Try
```

And I want:

```
"Hello",
"Sleep",
"try",
```

Hope anyone can help me

Comment: Do you want to add the quotes and comma around each word, or each line? (maybe that's the same thing in your case?)

Comment: Every word is on a new line, so it can both

Comment: Why does the title say you want to add ".", but the question says you want to add quotes and comma?

Comment: Please edit your title to match the question.

Comment: Around each word, or around the contents of the whole line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sed 's/.*/"&",/' file
```

In the replacement part of a substitution, `&` is replaced with whatever matched the original regular expression. `.*` matches the whole line.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've got one word per line, I'd use the following GNU sed command :

```
sed -i 's/.*/"\0",/' <your_file>
```

Where you replace `<your_file>` by the path to your file.

Explanation :

- `sed` means Stream EDitor ; it specialise in filtering and transforming text streams
- `-i` is it's in-place option : it means it will write the result of its transformation in the file it's working on
- `s/search/replace/` is `sed`'s search & replace command : it search for a pattern written as regular expression, and replace the matched text by something else
- `.*` is a regex pattern that will match as much as it can. Since `sed` works line by line, it will match a whole line
- `\0` is a back-reference to the whole matched string
- `"\0",` is the whole matched string, enclosed in quotes, followed by a comma.
- `s/.*/"\0",/` is a `sed` search&replace command that will match a whole line and enclose it in quotes, following it by a comma

Answer (score 2):

`sed` (the Stream EDitor) is one choice for this manipulation:

```
sed -e 's/^/"/;s/$/",/' file
```

There are two parts to the regular expression, separated by `;`:

1. `s/^/"/` means add a `"` to the beginning of each line.
2. `s/$/",/` means add a `",` to the end of each line.

The magic being the anchors for start of line (`^`) and end of line (`$`). The [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) has more details. It's worth learning sed.

Comment: `g` is redundant here, or am I missing something?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Yep, force of habit. Fixed.

Comment: also, you might want to replace `-e` with `-i`

Comment: @PatrickTrentin When the OP knows how `sed` operates, then he can choose to take the safety off.

Comment: never mind, I had some spurious data. (:

Answer (score 2):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991428/bash-shell-script-put-each-line-within-quotation)

Using **awk**

```
awk '{ print "\""$0"\","}' inputfile
```

Using **pure bash**

```
while read FOO; do
   echo -e "\"$FOO\","
done < inputfile
```

where `inputfile` would be a file containing the lines without quotes.

If your file has empty lines, **awk** is definitely the way to go:

```
awk 'NF { print "\""$0"\","}' inputfile
```

`NF` tells `awk` to only execute the print command when the Number of Fields is more than zero (line is not empty).

Answer (score 1):

Just to be different: perl

```
perl -lne 'print qq{"$_",}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple one liner:

```
sed -i 's/^/"/;s/$/",/' file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> echo $word
word
> echo "\""$word"\","
"word",
```

See [How to escape double quotes in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586627/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: You left out the comma.